# Shiny conditional tabs on the -input-

Tags: r, shiny

I have conditional tabs of output plots working fine by constructing plots output$VtPlot[1:n] on server.R side, then assembling into tabsetPanel with:

```
output$plotTabs = renderUI({
    nTabs <- as.numeric(input$nTraces)
    plotTabs <- lapply(paste0('VtPlot', 1:nTabs),function(nm)tabPanel(nm,plotOutput(nm)))
    do.call(tabsetPanel, plotTabs)
})
```

input$nTrace entry on only 1st (always displayed) tab on input side. Each of these potential plots are constructed with entries from input tabs that correspond in number. Then a

```
mainPanel(
  uiOutput('plotTabs')
)
```

in `ui.R`

However, I continue to struggle with making the -input- tabs conditional off `input$nTrace`.

I've tried building `tabPanels` on both `ui.R` and `server.R` sides a few different ways and bundling with a `do.call`, no luck so far. I'm assuming I'm missing something obvious?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

is the `Conditional Panel` you expect?

> Creates a panel that is visible or not, depending on the value of a JavaScript expression. The JS expression is evaluated once at startup and whenever Shiny detects a relevant change in input/output.

The following code is from `?conditionalPanel`, and `"input.plotType == 'hist'"` in your case would be `"input.nTraces== 1"` (Because the condition here is a javascript style):

```
sidebarPanel(
   selectInput(
      "plotType", "Plot Type",
      c(Scatter = "scatter",
        Histogram = "hist")),

   # Only show this panel if the plot type is a histogram
   conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.plotType == 'hist'",
      selectInput(
         "breaks", "Breaks",
         c("Sturges",
           "Scott",
           "Freedman-Diaconis",
           "[Custom]" = "custom")),

      # Only show this panel if Custom is selected
      conditionalPanel(
         condition = "input.breaks == 'custom'",
         sliderInput("breakCount", "Break Count", min=1, max=1000, value=10)
      )
   )
)
```

Comment: I have a version with conditional -panels- on ui.R side using Javascript conditionals. Struggling with input -tabs- appearing and disappearing per a radio button setting on first tab. I feel that makes a more clear interface, rather than blank tab when user activates the functionally inactive tab.

I have simple version working this way, similar to output  tabs in original code. The detail that is tripping me up is interaction on server.R side with: `    observe({updateSelectInput(session, 'nominal_tox', choices =attributes(model[[input$fabProc]])) })`
Thanks